# Flex Box buttons not centering

Tags: css, flexbox

My .buttons section is not centered. I want it to be centered. Also when I try to make my window bigger or smaller it stays that way, it never centers, I already added align-items and justify-content to center but makes almost no change.
thanks!

Snippet:

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}


/****************************/

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*! ????*/
  font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 450px;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: rgb(107, 111, 168);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 5px solid rgb(89, 93, 140);
  border-bottom: 20px solid rgb(89, 93, 140);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 25px 5px 10px 5px;
  /* Arriba | Derecha | Abajo | Izquierda */
  /* flex: 1 2 250px; */
  /* flex grow | flex shrink | flex bais*/
  /*! ????*/
}

#display {
  background-color: rgb(112, 234, 211);
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 25px;
  font-size: 40px;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 5% auto;
  border-bottom: 10px solid rgb(86, 176, 159);
  text-align: right;
}

.buttons {
  /* flex-flow: column wrap; */
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* Arriba | Derecha | Abajo | Izquierda */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  /* flex grow | flex shrink | flex bais*/
  font-family: 'Heebos', sans-serif;
  width: 50%;
}

.button {
  font-size: 30px;
  /* text-align: center; */
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: black;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 20%;
  font-family: 'Heebos', sans-serif;
  border: white;
  border-bottom: 6px solid rgb(211, 211, 211);
}


/* flex:2 1 400px; */


/* takes twice amount of extra space */

#cl {
  background-color: rgb(255, 42, 0);
  border-bottom: 6px solid rgb(205, 34, 0);
}

#equals {
  background-color: rgb(255, 136, 0);
  border-bottom: 6px solid rgb(217, 116, 0);
  width: 40%;
  /* flex-shrink: 1; */
}


/* @media (max-width: 600px) {
    
        .buttons {
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
    
        #display {
            font-size: 30px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Calculator</h1>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="display">0</div>
    <section class="buttons">
      <button class="button" id="cl">C</button>
      <button class="button" id="percent">%</button>
      <button class="button" type="button" id="sign">+/-</button>
      <button class="button" id="div">/</button>

      <button id="sevem" class="button">7</button>
      <button id="eight" class="button">8</button>
      <button id="nine" class="button">9</button>
      <button class="button" id="mult">x</button>
      <button id="four" class="button">4</button>
      <button id="five" class="button">5</button>
      <button id="six" class="button">6</button>
      <button class="button" id="sub">-</button>
      <button id="one" class="button">1</button>
      <button id="two" class="button">2</button>
      <button id="three" class="button">3</button>
      <button class="button" id="add">+</button>
      <button id="zero" class="button">0</button>
      <button id="dot" class="button">.</button>
      <button class="button" id="equals">=</button>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image]

Here is my code:
html:

```
**<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Heebo:wght@615&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="display">0</div>
        <section class="buttons" >
            <button class="button" id="cl">C</button>
            <button class="button" id="percent">%</button>
            <button class="button" type="button" id="sign">+/-</button>
            <button class="button" id="div">/</button>

            <button id="sevem" class="button">7</button>
            <button id="eight" class="button">8</button>
            <button id="nine" class="button">9</button>
            <button class="button" id="mult">x</button>
            <button id="four" class="button">4</button>
            <button id="five" class="button">5</button>
            <button id="six" class="button">6</button>
            <button class="button" id="sub">-</button>
            <button id="one" class="button">1</button>
            <button id="two" class="button">2</button>
            <button id="three" class="button">3</button>
            <button class="button" id="add">+</button>
            <button id="zero" class="button">0</button>
            <button id="dot" class="button">.</button>
            <button class="button" id="equals">=</button>
        </section>
    </div>

<script src="index.js"></script>


</body>

</html>**
```

css:

```
**/* path: live-server --no-css-inject */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2,
h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address,
big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small,
strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd,
ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption,
tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details,
embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav,
output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio,

video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header,
hgroup, menu, nav,

section {
    display: block;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
    quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/****************************/
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /*! ????*/
    font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 500px;
    height: 450px;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: rgb(107, 111, 168);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 5px solid rgb(89, 93, 140);
    border-bottom: 20px solid rgb(89, 93, 140);

    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 25px 5px 10px 5px;
    /* Arriba | Derecha | Abajo | Izquierda */
    /* flex: 1 2 250px; */
    /* flex grow | flex shrink | flex bais*/
    /*! ????*/
}

#display {
    background-color: rgb(112, 234, 211);
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 25px;
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 5% auto;
    border-bottom: 10px solid rgb(86, 176, 159);
    text-align: right;
}

.buttons {
    /* flex-flow: column wrap; */
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    /* Arriba | Derecha | Abajo | Izquierda */
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    /* flex grow | flex shrink | flex bais*/
    font-family: 'Heebos', sans-serif;
    width: 50%;
}

.button {
    font-size: 30px;
    /* text-align: center; */
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: black;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 20%;
    font-family: 'Heebos', sans-serif;
    border: white;
    border-bottom: 6px solid rgb(211, 211, 211);
}


/* flex:2 1 400px; */
/* takes twice amount of extra space */

#cl {
    background-color: rgb(255, 42, 0);
    border-bottom: 6px solid rgb(205, 34, 0);
}

#equals {
    background-color: rgb(255, 136, 0);
    border-bottom: 6px solid rgb(217, 116, 0);
    width: 40%;
    /* flex-shrink: 1; */
}

/* @media (max-width: 600px) {

    .buttons {
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    #display {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
} */**
```

Comment: Made a snippet of your code to allow us to better assist you here.

Comment: Are you trying to make it look like the picture?

Comment: is not the same as the picture, if you want to be the same as picture, just delete the `width: 50%` from `.buttons` parent... another thing is the .buttons didn't have `display: flex` so centering didn't work

Comment: Most of the time when your CSS becomes difficult to work with you have too much CSS which appears to be the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just edited `.buttons` section

- `display: flex`
- `flex-direction: row`
- `flex-wrap: wrap`

Didn't try to remove unnecessary styles

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2,
h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address,
big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small,
strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd,
ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption,
tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details,
embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav,
output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio,

video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header,
hgroup, menu, nav,

section {
    display: block;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
    quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/****************************/
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /*! ????*/
    font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 500px;
    height: 450px;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: rgb(107, 111, 168);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 5px solid rgb(89, 93, 140);
    border-bottom: 20px solid rgb(89, 93, 140);

    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 25px 5px 10px 5px;
    /* Arriba | Derecha | Abajo | Izquierda */
    /* flex: 1 2 250px; */
    /* flex grow | flex shrink | flex bais*/
    /*! ????*/
}

#display {
    background-color: rgb(112, 234, 211);
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 25px;
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 5% auto;
    border-bottom: 10px solid rgb(86, 176, 159);
    text-align: right;
}

.buttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    /* flex-flow: column wrap; */
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    /* Arriba | Derecha | Abajo | Izquierda */
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    /* flex grow | flex shrink | flex bais*/
    font-family: 'Heebos', sans-serif;
    width: auto;
}

.button {
    font-size: 30px;
    /* text-align: center; */
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: black;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 20%;
    font-family: 'Heebos', sans-serif;
    border: white;
    border-bottom: 6px solid rgb(211, 211, 211);
}


/* flex:2 1 400px; */
/* takes twice amount of extra space */

#cl {
    background-color: rgb(255, 42, 0);
    border-bottom: 6px solid rgb(205, 34, 0);
}

#equals {
    background-color: rgb(255, 136, 0);
    border-bottom: 6px solid rgb(217, 116, 0);
    width: 40%;
    /* flex-shrink: 1; */
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="display">0</div>
        <section class="buttons" >
            <button class="button" id="cl">C</button>
            <button class="button" id="percent">%</button>
            <button class="button" type="button" id="sign">+/-</button>
            <button class="button" id="div">/</button>

            <button id="sevem" class="button">7</button>
            <button id="eight" class="button">8</button>
            <button id="nine" class="button">9</button>
            <button class="button" id="mult">x</button>
            <button id="four" class="button">4</button>
            <button id="five" class="button">5</button>
            <button id="six" class="button">6</button>
            <button class="button" id="sub">-</button>
            <button id="one" class="button">1</button>
            <button id="two" class="button">2</button>
            <button id="three" class="button">3</button>
            <button class="button" id="add">+</button>
            <button id="zero" class="button">0</button>
            <button id="dot" class="button">.</button>
            <button class="button" id="equals">=</button>
        </section>
    </div>

<script src="index.js"></script>


</body>
```

Comment: Thankyou very much! it worked :), just a question, shoudn't the main container with display:flex make all of the items inside flex also? That's why I didn't add another display:flex to .buttons.